# rspec doesn't get the right value of the instance var

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller action with some instance variables which I want to test, here is my action code:

```
def index
    @users_list = get_response('accounts/by_tag/QuickcallAdmin')['users'].to_a
    @credit_admin = !@users_list.select{|h| h['email'] == current_user.email}.blank?
    @accounts_emails = Account.pluck(:email)
  end
```

and the spec code:

```
describe 'GET #index' do
    login_user
    let(:account) {create(:account)}

    it 'responds with 200' do
      get :index, :format => :html
      controller.instance_variable_set(:@users_list, [{"id"=>2, "email"=>"tes1@test.com", "tenant_id"=>1,"first_name"=>"valera","last_name"=>"rotari","phone_number"=>"89439438954", "tags"=>[{"name"=>"Program", "value"=>"my_company"}, {"name"=>"ProgramAdmin", "value"=>"new_program"}, {"name"=>"ProgramAdmin", "value"=>"new_program1"}, {"name"=>"QuickcallAdmin", "value"=>"q1"}, {"name"=>"CreditAdmin", "value"=>"q1"}]}])

      expect(assigns(:credit_admin)).to eql(true)
      expect(assigns(:accounts_emails)).to eql(["tes1@test.com"])
    end
  end
```

so as you can see I try to assign some hash which I usually get from the response of the api call, and after that to see if credit_admin and account_emails vars has the right value. The problem is if I pus some puts in spec after var assignation I see my value assigned, but the test fails because credit admin variable is false and is expected as true. I got the same code and put it rails console to make a test for myself, note I use the same hash, and I have the right true value. So it seems like @users_list var is not assigned right or something like this. Also @account_email is empty array, but I have account created from factory, so it should have some value in it, seems like a common problem for both of them

Comment: You're setting data after you've run `index`.

Comment: when I move controller.instance_variable_set before index I will have this variable as empty array after index

Answer (score 2):

so I did it in another way, changed my spec code to

```
describe 'GET #index' do
    login_user

    it 'responds with 200' do
      create(:account)
      allow(controller).to receive(:get_response).and_return({"users" => [{"id"=>2, "email"=>"tes1@test.com","tenant_id"=>1,"first_name"=>"valera","last_name"=>"rotari","phone_number"=>"89439438954","tags"=>[{"name"=>"Program", "value"=>"my_company"}, {"name"=>"ProgramAdmin", "value"=>"new_program"}, {"name"=>"ProgramAdmin", "value"=>"new_program1"}, {"name"=>"QuickcallAdmin", "value"=>"q1"}, {"name"=>"CreditAdmin", "value"=>"q1"}]}]})
      get :index, :format => :html

      expect(assigns(:credit_admin)).to eql(true)
      expect(assigns(:accounts_emails)).to eql(["tes1@test.com"])
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. You either need to set up your test data correctly, or stub methods that fetch data.